# Replacing Item in a list

Tags: replace, wolfram-mathematica

Doing a vertical reflection symmetry on dots on a screen, please consider the following.

```
scrWidthCM=40

originals={{14.2065, 10.609, 0.974938}, {19.5653, 6.92721, 0.974938}, 
           {30.4607,17.4802, 0.974938}, {27.4621, 10.0393, 0.974938}, 
           {15.915, 20.4278,0.974938}, {28.6921, 5.2132, 1.53205}, 
           {27.0317, 24.8346,1.53205}, {20.8853, 18.8588, 1.53205}}
```

Where each sublist corresponds to : {Xcoordinate,Ycoordinate,radius}

Applying the symmetrical transfer to each of the 8 points :

```
(scrWidthCM - #[[1]]) & /@originals
```

How could I replace the first value of each sublists rather than simply compute its reflected X coordinate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to directly modify your `originals` object:

```
originals[[All, 1]] = scrWidthCM - originals[[All, 1]]
```

If you want a copy, then use:

```
{scrWidthCM - #, ##2} & @@@ originals
```

Comment: Thank You, the second one actually solve my "real problem" as my originals is made out of 96 lists as the one I posted here. However what puzzle me is that, your code works applying it to originals[[1]] (the equivalent of the original posted here) as well as on originals, containing 96 lists like the on provided here. Could you explain me why ? Many Thanks !

Comment: Mmmmh plotting it, it actually does not work. I will simply map your solution over my big list :-)

Comment: @500, are you saying that the second line does what you want, but that your actual data has `ArrayDepth` equal to `3`?  In that case, I believe what you want is: `Apply[{scrWidthCM - #, ##2} &, data, {2}]` (this is the long form of `@@@` as used above, but with level specification `{2}` in place of `{1}`).

Comment: ({scrWidthCM - #, ##2} & @@@ \[Theta]riginals[[#]]) & /@ Range[96];   This is doing it.  I guess your proposed solution is neater ! Thank You !